# Distribution of final digits of random numbers in Python

Tags: python, random

There are two obvious ways to generate a random digit from 0 to 9 in Python. One could generate a random floating point number between 0 and 1, multiply by 10, and round down. Alternatively, one could use the `random.randint` method.

```
import random

def random_digit_1():
    return int(10 * random.random())

def random_digit_2():
    return random.randint(0, 9)
```

I was curious about what would happen if one generated a random number between 0 and 1, and kept the *last* digit. I didn't necessarily expect the distribution to be uniform, but I found the result quite surprising.

```
from random import random, seed
from collections import Counter

seed(0)
counts = Counter(int(str(random())[-1]) for _ in range(1_000_000))
print(counts)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({1: 84206,
         5: 130245,
         3: 119433,
         6: 129835,
         8: 101488,
         2: 100861,
         9: 84796,
         4: 129088,
         7: 120048})
```

A histogram is shown below. Note that 0 does not appear, since trailing zeros are truncated. But can anyone explain why the digits 4, 5, and 6 are more common than the rest? I used
Python 3.6.10, but the results were similar in Python 3.8.0a4.

[image: Distribution of final digits of random floats]

Comment: This has to do with the way that the string representations of floats are computed in Python. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. You'd get much more even results if you used the tenths digit (first after the decimal) rather than the last digit.

Comment: We store floats in binary representation (since our memory is also binary). `str` converts it to base-10 which is bound to cause problems. e.g. a 1-bit float mantissa `b0 -> 1.0` and `b1 -> 1.5`. The "last digit" will always be `0` or `5`.

Comment: `random.randrange(10)` is even more obvious, IMHO. `random.randint` (which calls `random.randrange` under the hood) was a later addition to the `random` module for people who don't understand how ranges work in Python. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring: `randrange` actually came second, after they decided the `randint` interface was a mistake.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh, ok. I stand corrected. I was sure randrange was 1st, but my memory isn't as good as it used to be. ;)

Comment: Note that `random.randrange(10)` guarantees that every digit has an equal chance of appearing, while `int(10*random.random())` might have subtly different chances.

Answer (score 25):

That's not "the last digit" of the number. That's the last digit of the *string `str` gave you* when passed the number.

When you call `str` on a float, Python gives you enough digits that calling `float` on the string will give you the original float. For this purpose, a trailing 1 or 9 is less likely to be necessary than other digits, because a trailing 1 or 9 means the number is very close to the value you'd get by rounding off that digit. There's a good chance no other floats are closer, and if so, that digit can be discarded without sacrificing `float(str(original_float))` behavior.

If `str` gave you enough digits to exactly represent the argument, the last digit would almost always be 5, except when `random.random()` returns 0.0, in which case the last digit would be 0. (Floats can only represent [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), and the last nonzero decimal digit of a non-integer dyadic rational is always 5.) The outputs would also be extremely long, looking like

```
>>> import decimal, random
>>> print(decimal.Decimal(random.random()))
0.29711195452007921335990658917580731213092803955078125
```

which is one of the reasons `str` doesn't do that.

If `str` gave you exactly 17 significant digits (enough to distinguish all float values from each other, but sometimes more digits than necessary), then the effect you're seeing would disappear. There would be a nearly uniform distribution of trailing digits (including 0).

(Also, you forgot that `str` sometimes returns a string in scientific notation, but that's a minor effect, because there's a low probability of getting a float where that would happen out of `random.random()`.)

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** Your example is not actually looking at the last digit. The last digit of a finite binary-represented mantissa converted to base-10 should always be `0` or `5`.

---

Take a look at the comment in [`cpython/pystrtod.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e80b561d442769631d66f1cc8813ac30f97378e/Python/pystrtod.c#L826):

```cpp
char * PyOS_double_to_string(double val,
                                         char format_code,
                                         int precision,
                                         int flags,
                                         int *type)
{
    char format[32];
    Py_ssize_t bufsize;
    char *buf;
    int t, exp;
    int upper = 0;

    /* Validate format_code, and map upper and lower case */
    switch (format_code) {
    // ...
    case 'r':          /* repr format */
        /* Supplied precision is unused, must be 0. */
        if (precision != 0) {
            PyErr_BadInternalCall();
            return NULL;
        }
        /* The repr() precision (17 significant decimal digits) is the
           minimal number that is guaranteed to have enough precision
           so that if the number is read back in the exact same binary
           value is recreated.  This is true for IEEE floating point
           by design, and also happens to work for all other modern
           hardware. */
        precision = 17;
        format_code = 'g';
        break;
    // ...
}
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) confirms this:

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision (2<sup>-53</sup> ≈ 1.11 × 10<sup>-16</sup>). If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double-precision representation, and then converted back to a decimal string with the same number of digits, the final result should match the original string. **If an IEEE 754 double-precision number is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits, and then converted back to double-precision representation, the final result must match the original number.**

Thus, when we use `str` (or `repr`), we are only representing 17 significant digits in base-10. This means some of the floating point number will be truncated. In fact, to get the exact representation, you need a precision of 53 significant digits! You can verify this as follows:

```
>>> counts = Counter(
...     len(f"{random():.99f}".lstrip("0.").rstrip("0"))
...     for _ in range(1000000)
... )
>>> counts
Counter({53: 449833,
         52: 270000,
         51: 139796,
         50: 70341,
         49: 35030,
         48: 17507,
         47: 8610,
         46: 4405,
         45: 2231,
         44: 1120,
         43: 583,
         42: 272,
         41: 155,
         40: 60,
         39: 25,
         38: 13,
         37: 6,
         36: 5,
         35: 4,
         34: 3,
         32: 1})
>>> max(counts)
53
```

Now using the maximum precision, here's the proper way to find the "last digit":

```
>>> counts = Counter(
...     int(f"{random():.53f}".lstrip("0.").rstrip("0")[-1])
...     for _ in range(1000000)
... )
>>> counts
Counter({5: 1000000})
```

Thus, the last digit is always `5`. (Or, in very rare cases, `0`.) This makes sense since:

```
2**0  == 1.0
2**-1 == 0.5
2**-2 == 0.25
2**-3 == 0.125
2**-4 == 0.0625
2**-5 == 0.03125
2**-6 == 0.015625
2**-7 == 0.0078125
2**-8 == 0.00390625
2**-9 == 0.001953125
...
2**-k == 0.[k-1 digits]5
```

And all mantissas are some partial sum of these coefficients.

---

**NOTE:** As pointed out by user2357112, the correct implementations to look at are [`PyOS_double_to_string`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e80b561d442769631d66f1cc8813ac30f97378e/Python/pystrtod.c#L1243) and [`format_float_short`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e80b561d442769631d66f1cc8813ac30f97378e/Python/pystrtod.c#L995), but I'll leave the current one in because it's more pedagogically interesting.

Comment: "Thus, when we use str (or repr), we are only representing 17 significant digits in base-10." - 17 is the maximum. If it was actually a fixed 17 digits, the effect in the question wouldn't appear. The effect in the question comes from the just-enough-digits-to-round-trip rounding `str(some_float)` uses.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong implementation of `PyOS_double_to_string`. That implementation is preprocessed out in favor of [this one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e80b561d442769631d66f1cc8813ac30f97378e/Python/pystrtod.c#L1243)

Comment: Regarding first comment: As mentioned, the exact representation of a floating point number (EDIT: with an exponent of 0) requires 53 significant digits, though 17 is enough to guarantee `float(str(x)) == x`. Mostly, this answer was just to show the assumption ("last digit of exact representation") made in the question was wrong, since the correct result is just `5`s (and an unlikely `0`).

Comment: 53 significant decimal digits is not enough. [Here's an example that takes a lot more.](https://ideone.com/N6BeyJ)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sorry, I meant with an exponent of 0. (Which is necessary to guarantee uniformity within the interval [0, 1].)